# cascades bb10 qfile remove

Tags: qt, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, qfile

i wanna delete/remove a file from storage. the file is store in the "/shared/photos/". this is how i store the file

```
QByteArray* data; //some image data
QImage image;
image.loadFromData(*data);
QFile outFile("shared/photos/"+filename);
outFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
image.save(&outFile, "PNG");
```

and i can successfully view the image file with this code :

```
QString filepath;
QString workingDir = QDir::currentPath();
filepath = "file://" + workingDir + "/shared/photos/"+filename;
```

and it's viewed with no problem.

the QString "filepath" contains this string

```
"file:///accounts/1000/appdata/com.example.Project.testDev_le_Project4b5f4904/shared/photos/02.jpg"
```

And now i tried to delete/remove this file from storage.
this is how i tried :

```
QString thumbnailImage = filepath;
// basically it contains string like filepath
//"file:///accounts/1000/appdata/com.example.Project.testDev_le_Project4b5f4904/shared/photos/02.jpg"
QFile thumb(thumbnailImage); 
bool ok = thumb.remove(); 
QString error = thumb.errorString(); 
if(ok){ qDebug() << "delete thumbnailImage success = " << ok; }
else{ qDebug() << "delete thumbnailImage failed !! "; }
```

and it's not working. the debug says "No such file or directory".

```
i also tried 
QFile::remove(thumbnailImage);
```

and still not working.
i also tried :

```
QFile::remove("/shared/photos/"+filename);
```

but still not working.
i also tried changing the workdir from `QDir::currentPath()` to `QDir::homepath()` and still no success.

so please tell me what exactly i should put in the QFile::remove() parameter.
the reference https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/qfile.html#remove said the parameter is QString filename.

```
bool QFile::remove ( const QString & fileName )
```

what exactly i should insert the parameter?
please help me guys.

thanks.

Regards,
Yoga Try Utomo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file path is wrong. It should not contain "file://". Furthermore, you have to open the file before removing it.

```
QFile thumb("shared/photos/" + filename);
thumb.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
thumb.remove();
thumb.close();
```